# Augmenting a filtration

Tags: measure-theory

I have a short question regarding the topic in the title.

Let $(\mathcal{F}_t)$ be a filtration on some probability space. Let $(B_n)$ be a sequence of events such that$B_n \in \mathcal{F}_{t+\frac{1}{n}}$. Define $B := \cap_{m\geq 1}\cup_{n\geq m} B_n$. Show that $B \in \mathcal{F}_{t+}$.

I have that $B \in \mathcal{F}_{t+}$ if and only $B \in \mathcal{F}_{s}$ for all $s > t$. So then I fix some arbitrary $s > t$. If I can show that $B \in \mathcal{F}_{s}$ then I will be done. I define $C_m = \cup_{n\geq m} B_n$. Clearly, $C_m \in \mathcal{F}_{t+\frac{1}{m}}$. I don't know how to proceed from here on.

Then I need to show that for any event $A$,
$$A\triangle B \subseteq \bigcup_{n\geq 1} A \triangle B_n$$
I can rearrange the terms on the rhs to get
$$A\triangle B \subseteq A \triangle \bigcup_{n\geq 1} B_n$$
I don't see why this should be true based on the definition of $B$. It is clear that $B$ is a subset of $\bigcup_{n\geq 1} B_n$. The difference $\bigcup_{n\geq 1} B_n \setminus A$ should be bigger than $B \setminus A$ but $A \setminus \bigcup_{n\geq 1} B_n$ should be bigger than $A \setminus B$. I am not sure what to do here. I hope someone can point out what I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Note that the sets $(C_m)_{m \in \mathbb{N}}$ are decreasing and therefore $$B = \bigcap_{m \geq 1} C_m = \bigcap_{m \geq M} C_m \in \mathcal{F}_{t+1/M}$$ for any $M \geq 1$.
2. Let $x \in A \backslash B = A \cap B^c$. Since $x \in B^c$, there exists $N$ such that $x \notin B_n$ for any $n \geq N$. Hence, $$x \in A \cap B_N^c \subseteq A \Delta B_N.$$ This shows $$A \backslash B \subseteq \bigcup_{n \geq 1} A \Delta B_n.$$
3. Let $x \in B \backslash A$. As $x \in B$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x \in B_N$. Thus, $$x \in B_N \backslash A \subseteq A \Delta B_N.$$ Consequently, $$B \backslash A \subseteq \bigcup_{n \geq 1} A \Delta B_n.$$